# What is the definitive link for C and C++ programming languages?

Tags: c++, c

Lately all modern programming languages have a definitive web site to support, distribute, learn the programming language, as well as community forums, e-mail lists and so on. Java has java.sun.com, python has python.org, etc.

However C/C++ does not seem to have such a site. Which site do you use, say in a document, to link for C or C++ programming language? Wikipedia entries don't count, although they might be perfect fit.

Founder's web sites? Or any other ideas?

Comment: Thing is C/C++ started before these definitive portals have sprung up...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The C Programming Language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/)

Answer (score 5):

Bjarne Stroustrup keeps a lot of interesting links on [his homepage](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/).  The [FAQ](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq.html) and [C++ glossary](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/glossary.html) are good references, but make sure you also check out [Did you really say that?](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq.html#really-say-that) for an interesting read.

Answer (score 5):

The definitive reference for C++ is [ISO/IEC 14882:2011](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=50372). This is the International Standard defining the language, the library and the semantics thereof. It's also probably far more than you need, and it costs $330 USD. You can get free [draft](http://www.dkuug.dk/jtc1/sc22/open/n3242/n3242.pdf) versions of the standard at the [committee website](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/) (and [elsewhere](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft)).

C is likewise defined by the International Standard [ISO/IEC 9899:2011](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=57853). As with C++,  [draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1494.pdf) versions available from the [committee website](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/).

Comment: The current draft for C99 TC3 can be obtained from http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Answer (score 4):

These languages have been around longer than the Internet as we know it.  A lot of the introductory texts are in dead-tree format.  Most of the online stuff is reference material, but there are newsgroups and such (I don't follow any of them).

[*The C Programming Language*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628)

Any reference for the C or C++ standard libraries.

**C++ Specific:**

[C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/)

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/)

Comment: I wouldn't call Boost a definitive site for C++. It's a definitive site for a set of *libraries*. C++ FAQ Lite is good though.

Comment: That's fair, but I threw boost in there because it's a very large, powerful, commonly used set of libraries for C++.  It provides many things that someone used to the Java, C#, or Python standard libraries would expect to have.

Comment: I guess boost for C++ is correct, as they are not doing just library stuff but also promoting and pushing C++ as other languages introducing new concepts, which are not easily available in C++. And it is a community site.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the C++ FAQ Lite page (the parashift site.) This one helped me tremendously in my writing style.

Answer (score 3):

For C++ there is [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/) and [SGI's STL page](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/) are good references. But they aren't much help learning the language itself.

Comment: They are blind reference sites, like automatically generated reference pages. They are not promoting the language and gathering a community around.

Comment: @serkan, your criticism of those sites is exactly correct, but they're still both lifesavers on occasion.  +1 for the usefulness of the links.

Comment: I have gotten lots of help with questions from the friendly folks at cplusplus.com.

Answer (score 3):

How about the *Usenet*:

- `comp.lang.c++.moderated` (for discussion about C++ Programming, moderated)
- `comp.lang.c++` (for discussion about C++ Programming)

  [URL for the two above](http://groups.google.com/groups/dir?sel=gtype%3D0%2Cusenet%3Dcomp.lang.c%2B%2B%2C&hl=en&)
- `comp.std.c++` (for discussion about the Standard)

  [URL for the one above](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/topics?hl=en&lnk)

Answer (score 2):

I guess people probably won't be needing a definitive website if they have the bible :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some C resources:

- C99 specification TC3 ([pdf](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf))
- comp.lang.c ([Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/topics))
- comp.lang.c.moderated ([Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c.moderated/topics))
- [GNU libc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/)
- [GNU libc mailing lists](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/resources.html#projectweb)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good links for both C and C++ covering websites and books, but one that's been overlooked is my favorite for C:

[Harbison and Steele](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013089592X)

Answer (score 0):

There's always [Boost](http://boost.org).

> Boost provides free peer-reviewed portable C++ source libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Zed the Sharkjumper's textbook: http://c.learncodethehardway.org/